# HTML 5 videos tags are showing up as invalid source in internet explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11

When i use the video tag to display a mp4 video, am getting invalid source in the internet explorer 11.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
</head>
<body> 
<video  width="400" height="300"  controls >
 <source src="Libraries\Documents\videos.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</body> 
</html>
```

**Tried the following but no luck**

1)Included meta tag with content as IE=11 and IE=Edge.

2)Included codecs in the type attribute

```
<source src="Libraries\Documents\bluetoothIphoneSecond.mp4" type='video/mp4;codecs="H.264/MPEG-4"'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the issue is related that your Internet Information Services (IIS) don't contain the .mp4 MIME type.

Please refer to the following steps to check/add the MP4 MIME type.

1. open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager,
2. Highlight Default Web Site on the left panel;
3. Double-click MIME Types on the right panel;
4. Scroll down the list and notice that there is no .mp4;
5. On the right panel again, click Add: at the first field, write .mp4 and on the field below write video/mp4.
6. Click OK and you are done. The screenshot like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BQrQ.png).
7. Restart IIS.

Then, retest your code.

I also create a sample on my side (using your code and IE 11.116.18362.0), it works well.